# Why is this code nto filtering values? pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```py
df_gri=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/b0219113/Documents/A_NCRT/Project Thena/Mapinfo/500 m/Main Sheet - Csv.csv')
df_gri[df_gri['Lat'] == 13.059216]
print(df_gri)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`df_gri[df_gri['Lat'] == 13.059216]`

Is only filtering for this call but not changing any data. If you want the result of the filtering to remain in df_gri, you have to change it to:

`df_gri = df_gri[df_gri['Lat'] == 13.059216]`